# Find a matrix B that satisfies A'A+lambda I=B'B, where A and B are the same size

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let `A` and `B` be two `(kxn)` complex matrices, where $k<n$.

How can I find a matrix `B` that satisfies

$A^HA+\lambda I=B^HB
$   ?

where I is the `(nxn)` identity matrix and `A` is known.

I tried with eigenvalue decomposition but the problem is that `B` has to be `(kxn)`. Could I truncate the matrix of eigenvalues based on the maximum `rank` of `B (=k)?` How could I express that in an elegant way?

Thanks

Comment: There will only be a satisfactory $B$ if $A'A$ and $A'A + \lambda I$ have the same rank, which will not can't possibly happen if $k < n$ and $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{A^HA}$ exists and is Hermitian, so $\big(\sqrt{A^H A} + i \sqrt{\lambda}I \big)^H \big(\sqrt{A^H A} + i \sqrt{\lambda}I \big) = ...$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom with Tom's solution the matrix B is not $(kxn)$. Any Alternative?